# Infinite product of polynomials what does it mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, formal-power-series

What is the canonical way to understand such things as

$$(1+q + q^2 + \ldots q^9)(1+q^{10} + q^{20} + \ldots q^{90})((1+q^{100} + q^{200} + \ldots q^{900}) \ldots \quad ?$$

It is a problem from a combinatorics course which I don't attend but rather solve problems from there sometimes.

So I know how to compute it but I don't like that no one explained what does it even mean. I can make sense of it in the following way. Define $\mathbb{K}[[x]]$ as  the limit if the diagram $$\mathbb{K}[x]/(q) \leftarrow \mathbb{K}[x]/(q^2) \leftarrow \ldots$$

in the category of, say, topological algebras (multi-normed) (each $\mathbb{K}[x]/(q^i)$ is finite dimensional vector space so it has just one norm and we put the limit topology on $\mathbb{K}[[x]]$.

In this topology the product in question converges to the correct answer.

What else can be done to understand problems like this?

Comment: Did you try just taking the algebraic interpretation? Simplify each term of the production into a rational polynomial. (Though, that might be what you meant by "I know how to compute it, but I don't like that no one explained what does it even mean")

Comment: I think you meant $x$ rather than $q$ in $\Bbb{K}[[x]]$. You can just take the inverse limit in the category of rings and you get the ring  $\Bbb{K}[[q]]$ of  [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) in $q$ over $\Bbb{K}$.   Technically, if you want to read the infinite product as a convergent sequence, then you would need to use the topology you propose, but it just amounts to the observation that the "infinite product" only involves a finite sum to give the coefficients of a monomial $q^k$ for given $k$.

Comment: Combinatorics works with generating functions as elements of the ring of formal power series, which is doted with the [Krull topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_of_a_ring#Krull_topology) in which the ideals $(x^k)$, for $k=0,1,2,...$ form a neighbourhood basis of $0$ . By the way, you said "finite dimensional vector space so it has just one norm". What you really want to say is only one topology that makes the projections to $\mathbb{K}$ continuous while a topology on $\mathbb{K}$ is chosen and fixed. Norms there are many. None of this is necessary, though.

Comment: To make more clear, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two formal power series, define $d(f(x),g(x))=2^{-v(f,g)}$, where $v(f,g)$ is the largest exponent $k$ such that $x^k$ divides $f(x)-g(x)$. The convergence of that product is taken in this distance.